# Laravel 5 sending information using get request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

In my project I use `www.example.com/test?prevUrl=test/3/home` this is working fine in development when inside my controller I do `$request->prevUrl` but doesn't work in production(returns `null`). can someone help?

edit= "The `query_string` is not being properly set i-e (`?prevUrl=something` ) and for that reason my paginator is also not working properly

Comment: Define doesn't work

Comment: edited question

Comment: edited my question again

Comment: There is not enough description to help you fix the problem. According to how you described your situation, the code should work, unless there is something else we are not aware of. Try switching between `production` and `development ` environments on your existing development machine and work it out from there

Comment: i am switching and it is working fine on development. I just don't understand what it is. pagination also works fine in development but not on production

Comment: Check your deployment. It's likely that your issue is not related to code.

Comment: what in deployment??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148536/discussion-between-overcoder-and-ahmed-khan).

Comment: Just curious... $request->prevUrl property is not documented in laravel docs. How does it even works? Well... it seems a issue with web session. Almost sure... previous URL is placed in web session. You had better check your session storage anyway. Make sure you have granted properly permissions for directories also well.

Comment: it is a query string sir ```www.example.com/tests?query_string```

Comment: Could you show us a bit of your code to understand where the problem is?

Comment: consider i am visiting a url ```www.example.com?prevUrl=something```.
So in my controller the ```dd($request->prevUrl```should return ```something``` but it is returning ```null```. this thing works fine in development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using ubuntu 16.04 nginx server. The problem was that $_GET session variables were not being set properly. so what I did was inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and inside `location /` block/ directive I changed `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like it...

**In web.php:**

```
Route::get('test','YourController@yourMethod');
```

**In Controller:**

```
public function yourMethod(){

//or return $request->query('prevUrl'); 
return $request->input('prevUrl');

}
```

Comment: i am using ```prevUrl``` as a query string. I dont think a wild card syntax should be used for that